# Does Interstitial ads help us to get more earning than Banner ads?

Tags: android, admob, adsense, ads

I am adding Google AdMob into my first Android application. I am wondering whether should I use Interstitial ads or not.

My question is: Does Interstitial ads help us to get more earning than Banner ads?

My app is an Education app. Any good reason to use Interstitial ads?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @StilesCrisis Close this delete this, but answer it in comment at least :p

Comment: @StilesCrisis: It relates to programming at some points. I have seen a lot of kind of this question here.

Comment: @StilesCrisis If it is not related to programming it is related to what? Which part of the stack could cover these kind of questions that only programmers could have a real answer for it?

Comment: This is a marketing question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is.... it depends.... I know, I know, it's kind of cop out answer, but it does.  For instance, you might make more on interstitials per view but if your user engagement drops severely or leads to a higher uninstall rate because of them, then you actually net a negative outcome.

It also depends on how sophisticated your app is and how large your user population is.  If you could partner with ad partners that serve ads/offers specifically your target demographic you could make a good CPM while annoying your users less.

Banners are typically less intrusive than interstitials and ruin the users experience less.

I'd think about other ways to monetize your app (which I'm guessing you already have) through affiliate sales or offering more valuable content that you could charge for.

That only scratches the tip of things, but I hope it helped.

Comment: No problem! Feel free to direct message me with some more questions if you have them.  Have lived through the same thing with some of my apps.